# Calculating median value of polygon from points in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, lidar, statistics

I have a point layer coming from LIDAR data containing x,y,z and intensity values. On the other hand I have a layer containing several polygons. All the points are inside the polygons.

I need to calculate the median Z value of each polygon using the points. I could do a spatial join, but it offers only the possibility of calculating mean values unfortunately, not median.

How do I proceed?

Comment: I'm not sure what version of ArcMap you are using, but there should be an option for median in the field map all the way back to ArcMap 9.2. Edit: I see what you mean; the option is there in the sidebar tool help, but you can't select it in field map.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Field Map, the available merge rules depend on the data type stored in the field.

To clarify, the field map option is available in the ArcToolbox spatial join tool, not in the spatial join dialog accessible from the Table of Contents right-click menu.

[image]